# What is the use of PURGE in DROP statement of Hive?

Tags: hive, purge

Hi Please describe the difference between both in hive with example.

Comment: did you at least look for it ?  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

Answer (score 28):

DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS] table_name [PURGE];

If you don't use purge the table goes to a Trash directory, from there the table can be recovered after drop it. But if you do use purge table won't go to Trash directory, so it can't be recovered.

Regards !!